# How do I format numeric values in a Panel widget?

Tags: python, format, bokeh, panel, text-formatting

Using the [Python library Panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/), I'm trying to format an IntSliderRange to `f"{the_slider_number} kr"` but the formatting argument in that class is not doing anything with the python text formatting tricks I am familiar with: 'kr', '{} kr', '{0} kr', etc.

Running `help(pn.widgets.IntRangeSlider)` tells me that I have to provide "A format string or bokeh TickFormatter" but I can't seem to find any relevant search results based on that.

Copilot suggests '0[.]0a' as an argument which does stuff to the format, namely express the numbers in thousands (1234 -> "1.2k"), but that's not at all what I want.

Does anyone recognize this formatting system? Where can I find out how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is the bokeh documentation about [formatters](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html) and in particular the section about the [predefiend formatters of the NumeralTickFormatter](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.NumeralTickFormatter.format). All these examples can you use and pass to your slider.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Slider
output_notebook()

slider = Slider(
    start=0,
    end=10,
    value=2,
    step=0.1,
    format ='$0,0.00'
)
show(slider)
```

[image: Slider with dollor sing in formatter]

In addition you can pass any instance of a formatter to the `format`. For example if you want a `€` sign, there is no existing string notation. But you could make use of the `PrintfTickFormatter` to modifiy the string.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Slider, PrintfTickFormatter
output_notebook()
slider = Slider(
    start=0,
    end=10,
    value=2,
    step=0.1,
    format = PrintfTickFormatter(format='€%.2f')
)
show(slider)
```

[image: Slider with euro sing in formatter]